# How to add a Background service in Ionic app

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, service, background

I try to use cordova Background Geolocation to send my position to a server in background. But when i put my app in background after some time it stop working. So I tried BackgroundFetch service https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-fetch but doesn't work: the error is:

```
You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "fetch" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
```

how can i add fetch to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in my Info.plist?

Answer (score 27):

Just do it as it is. Find the Info.plist in your project and add a pair of key/value like this,

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
</array>
```

Once you did it, rebuild it and the warning will disappear.